# How to create ImageShader in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I was playing with `ShaderMask` and it accepts two types of `Shaders`

```
Gradient & ImageShader
```

I can create `Gradient Shader` like this :

```
LinearGradient(colors: <Color>[
                      Colors.deepOrange,
                      Colors.blue,
                      Colors.green,
                      Colors.amber,
                    ]).createShader(bound)
```

but ***I couldn't find a way*** to create `ImageShader`.

When I try to create it like this :

```
ImageShader(
                    Image.network(
                      "https://product-image.juniqe-production.juniqe.com/media/catalog/product/cache/x800/401/62/401-62-101P.jpg",
                    ),
                    TileMode.mirror,
                    TileMode.mirror,
                    Float64List.fromList([1.0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0]));
              }
```

> it says :  Argument type `widget/Image` can't be assigned to parameter
>   type `ui/Painting/Image`

I know these two Images are different but I couldn't create ui/Painting/Image from widget/Image.

Also there might be an intuitive way to create `ImageShader`?

What is the right way to crate ImageShader in Flutter?

Comment: Did you use right type of Image?

Comment: Nop.. it seems like they are different Images.

Comment: Like: Future<ui.Image> load(String asset) async {

Comment: No I didn't use anything like that. can you help me with a snippet or resource?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use mix blend mode in flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62620579/how-to-use-mix-blend-mode-in-flutter)

Answer (score 5):

I see that it's an old question, and probably you already find the answer.
But I'll answer it anyway.

The problem is that [Image.network](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Image-class.html) creates Image widget (part of widget library) but you need [Image](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/Image-class.html) object which is part of dart:ui library.

Example with the image from the question:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:ui' as ui;

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
        body: SafeArea(
          child: MyHomePage(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  Future<ui.Image> loadUiImage(String url) async {
    final response = await http.get(url);
    response.bodyBytes;
    final completer = Completer<ui.Image>();
    ui.decodeImageFromList(response.bodyBytes, completer.complete);
    return completer.future;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder<ui.Image>(
        future: loadUiImage(
            'https://product-image.juniqe-production.juniqe.com/media/catalog/product/cache/x800/401/62/401-62-101P.jpg'),
        builder: (context, img) {
          return img.hasData
              ? ShaderMask(
                  blendMode: BlendMode.colorDodge,
                  shaderCallback: (bounds) => ImageShader(
                    img.data,
                    TileMode.clamp,
                    TileMode.clamp,
                    Matrix4.identity().storage,
                  ),
                  child: Container(
                    color: Colors.red,
                    height: 600,
                    width: 600,
                    child: Text('loaded'),
                  ),
                )
              : Text('loading');
        });
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are two classes called Image in flutter, in different packages.

There's the Widget, which behaves like a widget and can be instantiated from an asset, from memory or from the network through its named constructors.

There's also the ui package Image which is used when painting at a lower level

```
import 'dart:ui' as ui;
```

Example:

```
 ImageShader(
   Image.network(
      "https://product-image.juniqe-production.juniqe.com/media/catalog/product/cache/x800/401/62/401-62-101P.jpg",
   ),
   TileMode.mirror,
   TileMode.mirror,
   Float64List.fromList([1.0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0]),
 );
```

Comment: I think the question asks for a way to create ImageShader could you edit the answer  in a way others will be able to use it to easily create Image Shader? To convert widget/image to ui/widget there is another answer as well in Stackoverflow