# How to use mix blend mode in flutter?

Tags: flutter, mix-blend-mode, flutter-image

I have tried the blend mode that seems to be working for only color i.e colorblendmode. Is there any way to achieve the [mix-blend-mode as of CSS](https://alligator.io/css/exploring-blend-modes/)?

```
  Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          Image.asset(
            "asset/text.PNG",
            height: double.maxFinite,
            width: double.maxFinite,
            fit: BoxFit.fitHeight,
            color: Colors.red,
            colorBlendMode: BlendMode.multiply,
          ),
          Image.asset("asset/face.jpg",
              width: double.maxFinite,
              fit: BoxFit.fitHeight,
              color: Colors.red,
              colorBlendMode: BlendMode.multiply),
        ],
      ),
```

This results in something like:
[The output of code above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G9iHC.jpg)

What i want to get
[Output from CSS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mfNPp.jpg)

Comment: Don't know. But maybe you can play around with the different combinations of BlendMode.<type>. I mean, not just multiply. Another way could be try OverlayPainter and BlendMode.

Comment: I think I have a solution using RenderElements and BlendModes. Should be out later.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create ImageShader in Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61966819/how-to-create-imageshader-in-flutter)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Using RenderProxyBox and some painting, I was able to recreate the exact sample on the CSS website without asynchronously loading the image in your Flutter code.

Image using CSS (left) vs image using Flutter(right).

[image: Blendmode CSS vs Flutter]

[Read the article I wrote about this here](https://www.wilsonwilson.dev/articles/css-style-blending-using-flutter/)

To start, a BlendMask SingleChildRenderObject is created that creates a RenderProxyBox render object called RenderBlendMask is created. The child is painted with a BlendMode and an opacity.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';

// Applies a BlendMode to its child.
class BlendMask extends SingleChildRenderObjectWidget {
  final BlendMode blendMode;
  final double opacity;

  const BlendMask({
    required this.blendMode,
    this.opacity = 1.0,
    super.key,
    super.child,
  });

  @override
  RenderObject createRenderObject(context) {
    return RenderBlendMask(blendMode, opacity);
  }

  @override
  void updateRenderObject(BuildContext context, RenderBlendMask renderObject) {
    renderObject.blendMode = blendMode;
    renderObject.opacity = opacity;
  }
}

class RenderBlendMask extends RenderProxyBox {
  BlendMode blendMode;
  double opacity;

  RenderBlendMask(this.blendMode, this.opacity);

  @override
  void paint(context, offset) {
    // Create a new layer and specify the blend mode and opacity to composite it with:
    context.canvas.saveLayer(
      offset & size,
      Paint()
        ..blendMode = blendMode
        ..color = Color.fromARGB((opacity * 255).round(), 255, 255, 255),
    );

    super.paint(context, offset);

    // Composite the layer back into the canvas using the blendmode:
    context.canvas.restore();
  }
}
```

Now to blend two widgets (Not restricted to images), just add the widget you want to blend above another using a stack, and wrap it in your BlendMode.

```dart
class ImageMixer extends StatelessWidget {
  const ImageMixer({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SizedBox.expand(
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            SizedBox.expand(
              child: Image.asset(
                'images/sky.jpg',
              ),
            ),
            BlendMask(
              opacity: 1.0,
              blendMode: BlendMode.softLight,
              child: SizedBox.expand(
                child: Image.asset(
                  'images/monkey.jpg',
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

That produces the image above, and it works exactly like the CSS example.

Comment: No problem @ReikoDev. I should probably link to the article I wrote about it in case you're interested. https://www.wilsonwilson.dev/articles/css-style-blending-using-flutter/

Comment: Thanks once again @Wilson! I'm playing with canvas and this helps a lot!
One question, when you have a custom layout (e.g.  made on Illustrator), something like this https://ibb.co/WV3JxZd/, which approach do you use to make it real on flutter?

Comment: @ReikoDev Oh wow, lots and lots of custom paint. I don't believe it's a realistic or good idea to build everything with flutter though. For things like the stars, the *curtains*, the banners, and probably the containers, you'd be better off with raw design files.

For reactive components like the progress bar, you'd be safe in custom paint's hands :D

Comment: @WilsonWilson I'm using this, but it is rather expensive so I tried wrapping it in a `RepaintBoundary` but that behaves weirdly, any tips?

Answer (score 10):

Try [ShaderMask](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ShaderMask-class.html).
[BlendModes](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/BlendMode-class.html)

Example of use:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:typed_data';
import 'dart:ui' as ui;

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
        body: SafeArea(
          child: MyHomePage(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  Future<ui.Image> loadUiImage(String imageAssetPath) async {
    final data = await rootBundle.load(imageAssetPath);
    final completer = Completer<ui.Image>();
    ui.decodeImageFromList(Uint8List.view(data.buffer), completer.complete);
    return completer.future;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder<ui.Image>(
        future: loadUiImage('assets/cara_img.png'),
        builder: (context, img) {
          return img.hasData
              ? ShaderMask(
                  blendMode: BlendMode.colorDodge,
                  shaderCallback: (bounds) => ImageShader(
                    img.data,
                    TileMode.clamp,
                    TileMode.clamp,
                    Matrix4.identity().storage,
                  ),
                  child: Image.asset('assets/code.png'),
                )
              : Container(
                  color: Colors.red,
                  height: 100,
                  width: 100,
                  child: Text('loading'),
                );
        });
  }
}
```

code.png:
[image: code.png]
cara_img.png:
[image: cara_img.png]

Results:
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: That's a fantastic solution, but it's a bit bulky and you have to load images asynchronously. Why not use RenderObjects?