# How to change blend mode of text in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

```
         Expanded(
            flex: 1,
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 80, right: 230),
              child: Text(
                'Gifts \n& Wishes',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontFamily: 'GreatVibes',
                  fontSize: 42,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
```

I currently have this:

[image]

but i want this:

[image]

how to change the blend mode of this text in flutter?

Comment: Can you try with ColorFilter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For color blending 2 Widgets, especially if we want to blend **images** or other **color texture** with **text**, we must take advantage of the core Paint function of the Flutter canvas, to allow the Blend effect, just like in CSS, SVG or Photoshop-like applications.

Here is a complete example, based on [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64737622/4605422):

Create a **blendmask.dart** file and paste the following code:

```
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';

class BlendMask extends SingleChildRenderObjectWidget {
  final BlendMode blendMode;
  final double opacity;

  BlendMask({
    required this.blendMode,
    this.opacity = 1.0,
    Key? key,
    Widget? child,
  }) : super(key: key, child: child);

  @override
  RenderObject createRenderObject(context) {
    return RenderBlendMask(blendMode, opacity);
  }

  @override
  void updateRenderObject(BuildContext context, RenderBlendMask renderObject) {
    renderObject.blendMode = blendMode;
    renderObject.opacity = opacity;
  }
}

class RenderBlendMask extends RenderProxyBox {
  BlendMode blendMode;
  double opacity;

  RenderBlendMask(this.blendMode, this.opacity);

  @override
  void paint(context, offset) {
    context.canvas.saveLayer(
        offset & size,
        Paint()
          ..blendMode = blendMode
          ..color = Color.fromARGB((opacity * 255).round(), 255, 255, 255));

    super.paint(context, offset);

    context.canvas.restore();
  }
}
```

and this is your **main.dart**:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'blendmask.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Blend Color Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.deepPurple),
        useMaterial3: true,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Title"),
      ),
      body: SizedBox.expand(
      child: Stack(
        children: [
          SizedBox.expand(
            child: Image.network(
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
                "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1620641788421-7a1c342ea42e?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA&s=a0c8d632e977f94e5d312d9893258f59&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1355&q=80"),
          ),
          BlendMask(
            opacity: 1.0,
            blendMode: BlendMode.difference,
            child: const SizedBox.expand(
              child: Text(
                "\n \n This is \n \t\t a Title ",
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 100,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                  color: Color.fromARGB(255, 53, 250, 119),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
    );
  }
}
```

This is the result:
Notice you can change to **different color blend modes**.

[image]

Comment: it didnt work mate. at the end i decided to embed the text into the photo itself

Comment: How didn't work? Both methods work perfectly. I can add a full example if you need it.

Comment: yes it will be helpful if you provide the example. I want the `Text()` widget blend mode to change to overlay, like we can do in figma...Its not a picture, it the text's blend mode I want to change.

Comment: @MNBWorld Here is the full trick for what you asked. Good luck with your app.